# Global variable is working on other conditions except this one in python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, global

Good day to everyone. I need help with my python program. I am almost done making a police profile system wherein you can input and search. The problem I have is in the search function. Here is the bit of the source code to get started.

```
    global Value
    def config1():
            Entry1.config(state="normal")
            Entry1.delete(first=0,last=99)
            Entry1.insert(0,"LastName")
            Entry1.config(state="disabled")
            ThisEntry.delete(first=0,last=99)
            Value = Police['text']

    def config5():
            Entry1.config(state="normal")
            Entry1.delete(first=0,last=99)
            Entry1.insert(0,"LastName")
            Entry1.config(state="disabled")
            ThisEntry.delete(first=0,last=99)
            Value = Visitor['text']

    def Search():
            Entry1.config(state="normal")
            x = Entry1.get()
            y = ThisEntry.get()
            Entry1.config(state="disabled")
            global Value

            if x == "LastName" and Value == "POLICE IDENTITY":
                    z = 0
                    ThisText.config(state="normal")
                    ThisText.delete("1.0","end")
                    c.execute("SELECT LastName FROM Police WHERELastName=?",(y,))
                    row = c.fetchall()
                    for a in row:
                            c.execute("SELECT * FROM Police WHERE LastName=?",(y,))
                            row = c.fetchall()

            elif x == "LastName" and Value == "VISITOR":
                    z = 0
                    ThisText.config(state="normal")
                    ThisText.delete("1.0","end")
                    ThisText.insert(INSERT,"VISITORS")
                    c.execute("SELECT LastName FROM Visitors WHERE LastName=?",(y,))
                    row = c.fetchall()
                    for a in row:
                            ThisText.insert(INSERT,"\n\n")
                            ThisText.insert(INSERT,"Visitor Number: ")
                            ThisText.insert(INSERT,row[z][0])
                            ThisText.insert(INSERT,"\n")
                            ThisText.insert(INSERT,"First Name: ")
                            ThisText.insert(INSERT,row[z][1])
                            ThisText.insert(INSERT,"\n")
                            ThisText.insert(INSERT,"Middle: ")
                            ThisText.insert(INSERT,row[z][2])
                            ThisText.insert(INSERT,"\n")
                            ThisText.insert(INSERT,"Last Name: ")
```

I used the functions `def config1():` and `def config5():` just to change the value of the `Value`. I declared the `Value` as `global` since I need it just for changing the value.

The main goal is that the condition will return a row if the value is equal to the record that I want to search and if it is equal to the type of record that I want to search which is the `Value`.

So if I search for the `LastName` in Police Identity, it would return a row. Same with searching for Visitor.

If I search for the last name in the Police Identity Tab, it returns a row properly. But whenever I try to search for the last name in the Visitor Tab, it returns this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
       return self.func(*args)
       File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\School Files (Don't Touch)\Project in SE\Project in SE.py", line 1420, in Search
       elif x == "LastName" and Value == "POLICE IDENTITY":
       NameError: name 'Value' is not defined
```

I tried to declare the global variable on the function itself also but it still doesn't work.  I really don't get why it works on one condition but doesn't work on the other condition. I don't know if Python is playing a game on me or something. Btw I don't think there are any duplicates for this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: Can you atleast tell me what is the error in my program? :(

Comment: The error here relates to a condition `elif x == "LastName" and Value == "POLICE IDENTITY":`, which isn't in the code sample you give. In general, the `global Value` declaration needs to be in the functions that *assign* to `Value` (`config1` and `config5`) rather than in the function that refers to `Value` (`Search`)

Comment: Simply amazing. My program worked after this one. Kudos to you sir Stuart. Next time I'll try to include the complete sample code so I won't confuse anyone in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the error seems to be triggered on the 2nd condition rather than the 1st - I suspect there is some other bug - but in general you need to declare the global variable in the functions that assign to `Value`. This means adding `global Value` to your `config1` and `config5` functions.

The `global Value` declaration is *not* required within the `Search` function, because the programme should, by default, search for `Value` among global variables after failing to find it among the local variables.

The following code illustrates why an error might be triggered on the 2nd condition instead of the 1st:

```
global x

def foo():
    something = False
    if something and x == 10:
        print "Yes"
    elif x == 50:
        print "No"

foo()
```

This causes an error:

> line 15, in foo
>       elif x == 50:
>
> NameError: global name 'x' is not defined

Although `x` was declared as a global, no value was assigned to it. This doesn't cause an error on the first condition `if something and x == 10`, because `something` is False so the condition relating to `x` is never reached. It is only when the programme reaches the 2nd condition that it can't avoid trying to evaluate `x`, and then raises an error.